# Understanding of instanceof operator

Tags: javascript

I found very strange thing about performing "instanceof" on primitive objects like strings, numbers, booleans, etc. Explain please anybody this code:

```
var str = 'A string';
var num = 1;
var bool = true;

str  instanceof str.constructor; // returns false
num  instanceof num.constructor; // returns false
bool instanceof bool.constructor; // returns false
```

Comment: What's so strange about that? *Primivite values* are no objects, so they're not instances of any "class" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` operator tests only object. You try to test primitives, so it returns false.
[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Answer (score 1):

As of the definition given by MDN:

> The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in
>   object's prototype chain.

If you want to call the constructor use the new operator. Try like so:

```js
var str = new String('A string');
```